# Get first example element from filtered aggregation pySpark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Table:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|id       |path     |error    |message  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      1  |    a.a.a|   true  |   "aaa" |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      2  |    a.a.a|   true  |   "bbb" |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      2  |    a.a.a|   true  |   "bbc" |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      2  |    a.a.b|   false |   "ccc" |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I have pySpark query:

```
data.groupBy('id', 'path')\
.agg(
    sum(when(col('error') == 'true', 1).otherwise(0)).alias('count'),
).show()
```

How can I add a new column with first example element that have `col('error') == 'true'`? I want a table with elements `id, path, count, exampleItem`.
Function `first().alias('exampleItem')` works, but returns elements that do not necessarily match the condition above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is define a column that only contains the message in the case where the error is true, and null otherwise using the `when` function. Then, the `first` function used with `ignorenulls` set to true will give you what you expect.

```py
d = [(1, "a.a.a", True, "aaa"), (2, "a.a.a", True, "bbb"),
     (2, "a.a.a", True, "bbc"), (2, "a.a.b", False, "ccc")]
data = spark.createDataFrame(d, ['id', 'path', 'error', 'message'])

data\
    .groupBy('id', 'path')\
    .agg(F.sum(F.when(F.col('error') == 'true', 1).otherwise(0)).alias('count'),
         F.first(F.when(F.col('error'), F.col('message')), ignorenulls=True).alias('exampleItem'))\
    .show()
```

```
+---+-----+-----+-----------+
| id| path|count|exampleItem|
+---+-----+-----+-----------+
|  2|a.a.a|    2|        bbb|
|  1|a.a.a|    1|        aaa|
|  2|a.a.b|    0|       null|
+---+-----+-----+-----------+
```

For the last row, the null value is due to the fact that no message meet the desired requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `first` with the `ignorenulls=True` option and a `case when` statement to get the first message with `error = true`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.groupBy(
    'id', 'path'
).agg(
    F.sum(F.when(F.col('error') == 'true', 1).otherwise(0)).alias('count'),
    F.first(
        F.when(F.col('error') == 'true', F.col('message')),
        ignorenulls=True
    ).alias('exampleItem')
).orderBy('id', 'path')

df2.show()
+---+-----+-----+-----------+
| id| path|count|exampleItem|
+---+-----+-----+-----------+
|  1|a.a.a|    1|        aaa|
|  2|a.a.a|    2|        bbb|
|  2|a.a.b|    0|       null|
+---+-----+-----+-----------+
```

However, note that there is no ordering column defined in your sample dataframe, so `first` has no concrete meaning and will only return a random element with `error = true`. Presumably there should be a timestamp column which can be used to order the dataframe within each id/path partition.